# Google App Engine request FROM a country

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm using GAE for a server, part of what it does is to user URLFetch to get data from another server, out of my control. That server now blocks IPs not from one country to try and stop DdOS attacks.

Is there a way to set what IP / what country the App Engine servers send requests from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can only choose USA or European data centres and only on paid support accounts.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I got round the problem by having someone host a script that just forwarded the file around the block.